# Cron jobs created on ubuntu is not working as expected

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a python file which is created on windows which is also working on ubuntu OS aswell. I have a VPS in hostinger platform where this script should run in daily basis. But triggers on the scheduled period is not happening.

I have created a Cronjob using the command

```
crontab -e
```

the Cron syntax used:

```
* 12 * * * python filpath/script.py
```

but the file is not getting executed. I have checked the system logs their is nothing related to cron jobs. Am not sure where things went wrong.

Comment: is `python filpath/script.py` real value you have in your cronjob?

Comment: no. I just mentioned it as an example cronjob has the actual path and filename written in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You incorrectly assume working directory will be the same for cronjob that is for your current session in i.e. shell. It will not. You need to change that in cron or use absolute path to your script. The former sounds better for me as I assume your scripts might have troubles working properly otherwise:

```
* 12 * * * cd "<PATH/TO/YOUR/PROJECT>" && python filpath/script.py
```

assuming your `script.py` lives in `filpath` folder located in `<PATH/TO/YOUR/PROJECT>`.

You stil can have the same problem with `python` itself, but it's more likely that it will be in `PATH` cron uses (you can change that to absolute path). BTW: when cron job fails, then you (I mean the user on which account the cron is running) shall receive a system mail with more detailed error. So check that too if you can access it.

Comment: You are awesome. I have been banging my head for while with this issue. Changing it to the working directory did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in cron tab:

```
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/file/script.py /path/to/file/script.log
```

Comment: i have just modified syntax to */2 * * * * . to exceute it every 2 mins for testing purposes. I can see the entries happening every 2 mins on the logs. But the ptyhon script is not getting triggered even the log file is not getting created.